# Why is pasar here only conjugated in the 3rd person

Tags: verbos

I often use this French site to find verb conjugations of Spanish verbs.

But something peculiar happened when I looked up the conjugations for pasar, it is only conjugated in the 3rd person. Why is that please?

Thank you.

link [enter link description here](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/espagnol/verbe/pasar.php)
image
[image]

Comment: Work in progress??? You should check the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/pasar#conjugacionfvAf3jU) instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Spanish, but a website.

Answer (score 1):

El verbo pasar presenta numerosos significados. El Diccionario de la lengua española
(RAE, 2019), por ejemplo, incluye en la acepción 52 de este verbo el significado de ‘ocurrir, acontecer, suceder’.

Se refiere a que cuando se utiliza el verbo "Pasar", con el sentido de *ocurrir, suceder o acontecer*, se utiliza de manera mayoritaria en tercera persona del singular y plural, o en infinitivo gerundio y participio en forma impersonal.

Estos verbos, ocurrir, suceder o acontecer, son verbos defectivos ó incompletos, que significa que carecen de ciertas formas de conjugación o tiempos y que por su significado o sentido solo se conjugan en tercera persona.

Con este mismo significado (‘suceder, ocurrir, acontecer) Moliner (2016: 2201) lo describe como verbo inacusativo.

Actualmente en *Español* nos encontramos con la alternancia entre;

- La estructura de relativo (lo que pasa que, la casa...),
- La enfática de relativo (lo que pasa es que, la)
- La estructura breve o reducida (pasa que, la casa...), de uso oral coloquial.

Eso pasaba, (en sentido de suceder, ocurrir ó acontecer), cuando yo tenía cinco años. Pasa que ya no vivo allí.

P.D Sin entrar en tecnicismos, se busca incluir el verbo "pasar" dentro de la lista de verbos llamados terciopersonales, estos son verbos que por lo general solamente se conjugan en tercera persona del singular o del plural, como acaecer (algo acaece, las cosas acaecen, pero normalmente ni yo ni nosotros ni tú ni vosotros realizan esa acción).

*Diego*

Answer (score 0):

If you look up pasar in the [Dictionary of the Royal Academy](https://dle.rae.es/pasar?m=form) you will find many, many meaning for the verb. At the tope there is a helpful note.

> U. solo en infinit., en ger., en part. y en 3.ª pers. en acep. 52.

the last part of which is relevant here: it is used in the third person in meaning 52. The full translation is Used only in the infinitive, gerundive and participle and in the third person in meaning 52. Bear in mind that I am not a professional translator and the exact technical words there may be slightly off.

> 52. intr. Ocurrir, acontecer, suceder.

So it looks as though the French dictionary you quote is only concerned with telling you about that usage and not all the others. It is, to be fair, a common usage.

Using the DLE as it is known these days is always a good plan as it it the authoritative dictionary for Spanish.